# Spring Thymeleaf pass object attribute to href button submit

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to do a form action where I show selected lists for each of some grouped values. After the user chooses a value in one of these lists I want to put the name of this object into a button link as a parameter but the parameter values are empty. I don't know how can I do it.

Here is my code for that:

In my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/teacher/depts", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String depts(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("deptsfields", fieldOfStudyService.findAllFieldsForAllDepartments());
    model.addAttribute("field", new FieldOfStudy());

    return "teacher/depts";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/deptsfields", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String deptsfields(@ModelAttribute(value="field") FieldOfStudy field) {
    return "teacher/depts";
}
```

And my html page:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/deptsfields}" th:object="${field}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Wydział</th>
            <th>Kierunek</th>
        </tr>

        <tr th:each="entry : ${deptsfields}">
            <td th:text="${entry.getKey().details.departmentFullName}"
                th:value="${entry.getKey().details.departmentFullName}"
                th:field="*{details.department.details.departmentFullName}"></td>
            <td>
                <select id="fieldslist" class="form-control" th:field="*{details.fieldOfStudyName}">
                    <option selected="selected" value="">Wybierz...</option>
                    <option th:each="field : ${entry.getValue()}" th:value="${field.details.fieldOfStudyName}" th:text="${field.details.fieldOfStudyName}"></option>
                </select>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>

    <a th:href="@{/teacher/groups(field=${field.details.fieldOfStudyName}, dept=${field.details.department.details.departmentFullName})}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Dalej</a>
</form>
```

After click the button I'm redirected to this page:

```
http://localhost:8080/teacher/groups?field={here should be name but is empty}&dept={here should be name but is empty}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Ok I solved this problem. If someone want to know, I change for normal sumbit button and in my controller I use RedirectAttributes as method parameters and add parameters whose I wanted in method redirectAttributes.addAttribute). It works.

Answer (score 4):

You have an error in your link, try this

```
  <a th:href="@{'/teacher/groups?field=' + ${field.details.fieldOfStudyName} + '&dept=' + ${field.details.department.details.departmentFullName}}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Dalej</a>
```